# checkboxes and number fields set by jquery appear for a split second, then suddenly disappear

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I created a simple html file that makes ajax requests to get data from a database table.

Some columns are not updated through ajax. They are manually given inputs in this page. As every `ajax` call refreshes the page data, I wrote `storeVars()` and `putVars()` to store the input values before refreshing and to set the stored values after refreshing respectively. But this doesn't work :(

JavaScript:

```
function createList() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "fetch_registered_list.php?event_id=1",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            $('#table_data tr').not(':first').remove();
            if (data != '' || data != undefined || data != null) {
                var html = '';
                $.each(data, function(i, item) {
                    html += "<tr><td>" + data[i].sno + "</td>" + "<td>" + data[i].name + "</td>" + "<td>" + data[i].email + "</td>" + "<td>" + data[i].phone + "</td>" + "<td><input class='check' name='" + i +
                        "' type='checkbox'/></td>" + "<td><input class='score' name='" + data[i].email + "' type='number'/></td></tr>"
                })
                $('#table_data tr').first().after(html);
            }

        }
    });
}



$(document).ready(function() {
    createList();
    setInterval(function() {
        storeVars();
        createList();
        putVars();
    }, 5000);
});

var checkboxes = new Array();
var scores = new Array();

function storeVars() {
    $('#table_data tbody tr:not(:first-child) td:nth-child(5)').each(function() {
        checkboxes.push($(this).find('.check').is(':checked'));
    });
    $('#table_data tbody tr:not(:first-child) td:nth-child(6)').each(function() {
        scores.push($(this).find('.score').val());
    });
}

function putVars() {
    $('#table_data tbody tr:not(:first-child) td:nth-child(5)').each(function() {
        $(this).find('.check').prop('checked', true);
    });
    $('#table_data tbody tr:not(:first-child) td:nth-child(6)').each(function() {
        $(this).find('.score').val('44');
    });
}
```

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="heading">
            <h1>Event One</h1>
        </div>
        <form method="post">
            <table id="table_data">
                <tr>
                    <td><strong>S.no.</strong></td>
                    <td><strong>Name</strong></td>
                    <td><strong>Email</strong></td>
                    <td><strong>Phone</strong></td>
                    <td><strong>Participated</strong></td>
                    <td><strong>Score</strong></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <footer>
                <input id="button" type="button" name="submit" value="Announce Winners" />
            </footer>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: The topic of your question does not tie with the question itself. Really hard to comprehend your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you must reset your arrays at each new storage, or you'll have arrays with exponentional new entries. Secondly your `putVars()` function is incorrect, it must check the values of each arrays in order to recreate the correct data in the corresponding input.
So update your document ready function to declare your two arrays.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var checkboxes,
        scores;

    createList();
    setInterval(function() {
        storeVars();
        createList();
        putVars();
    }, 5000);
});
```

Then reset your two arrays every storage.

```
function storeVars() {
    checkboxes = new Array();
    scores = new Array();

    $('#table_data tbody tr:not(:first-child) td:nth-child(5)').each(function() {
        checkboxes.push($(this).find('.check').is(':checked'));
    });
    $('#table_data tbody tr:not(:first-child) td:nth-child(6)').each(function() {
        scores.push($(this).find('.score').val());
    });
}
```

Finally update your putVars() function like this.

```
function putVars() {
    $('#table_data tbody tr:not(:first-child) td:nth-child(5)').each(function(index) {
      if(checkboxes[index] == true) {
        $(this).find('.check').prop('checked', true);
      }
      else {
        $(this).find('.check').prop('checked', false);
      }
    });
    $('#table_data tbody tr:not(:first-child) td:nth-child(6)').each(function(index) {
        $(this).find('.score').val(scores[index]);
    });
}
```

[working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0gz3cuea/)

Comment: sorry. I forgot to mention. I wrote     $(this).find('.check').prop('checked',true) and $(this).find('.score').val('44') just to keep filling the fields for debugging.
Thanks @smdsgn.. But the values still continue to disappear. :(

Comment: Can you post a sample of your data return by your ajax function in your question ?